# How to clear my pending edit question queue?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I edited some question and sometime when I want to edit new question see a message Like: ***The pending edit queue is full***, and I must wait to one of edited question review and edit new question.

Now I want to know could I find my edited question that not reviewed and cancel that to clear my edited question queue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't cancel your pending suggested edits.

Comment: Your suggested edits, including those still under review, are [listed in your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4972721/combo-ci?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). There currently is just one.